# insertion of an html tag between rows of a table

Tags: html

Can I insert any html tag inbetween table rows such that the inserted tag serves as a parent node for the rows after that tag. Like

```
<table>
  <tr><td>group 1</td></tr>
  //insert tag here
     <tr><td>patent 1 in group 1</td></tr>
     <tr><td>patent 2 in group 1</td></tr>
  //end tag here
</table>
```

I want the inserted tag to be the parent node for the rest of rows. Or is it possible to make the 1st row as parent node for the rest of the rows

Edit: What I actually want to achieve

I want to create a table with multiple rows in which one row will be a group name and it will serve as parent row, this row will contain sub rows and I should be able to drag and drop rows from one group to another which I am currently able to do with TableDnd Plugin but I need the id of the parent row to which the sub row is draged.

If I do something like this

```
<table id="sort">
    <tbody id = 'group_1'>
    <tr id="1"><td>1</td><td>One</td><td><input type="text" name="one" value="one"/></td></tr>
    <tr id="2"><td>2</td><td>Two</td><td><input type="text" name="two" value="two"/></td></tr>
    <tr id="3"><td>3</td><td>Three</td><td><input type="text" name="three" value="three"/></td></tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody id = 'group_2'>
    <tr id="4"><td>4</td><td>Four</td><td><input type="text" name="four" value="four"/></td></tr>
    <tr id="5"><td>5</td><td>Five</td><td><input type="text" name="five" value="five"/></td></tr>
    <tr id="6"><td>6</td><td>Six</td><td><input type="text" name="six" value="six"/></td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I am able to drag rows with in one tbody but not from one `tbody` to another. How can I get that any other solution?

Comment: you may use comments, i.e. `<!-- ROW-GROUP-1 -->`

Comment: I need to set the ID of the 1st row in that tag so that I get it as a parent node id

Comment: You can add tags to make inner rows as inner/nested table.

Comment: i would prefer to use thead and tbody tags..

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Can't you be good enough with the correct classes set?

Comment: Actually I want to create a table with multiple rows in which one row will be a group name and this row will contain sub rows and I should be able to drag and drop rows from one group to another which I able to do now bit I need the group id to which the sub row is draged

Comment: @ZohaAliKhan I can't understand: why you are `able to drag rows with in one tbody but not form one tbody to another` using multiple `TBODY` tags?

Answer (score 2):

The only valid ways to group table rows are `thead`, `tbody`, and `tfoot` elements. The normal way to group data rows is `tbody`.

Comment: When I create mutiple tbody I cannot drag the rows rom one group to another which is the limitation of TableDnD plugin and I need to be able to drag rows from one group to another

Answer (score 1):

Use css classes to group your rows:

```
<table>
     <tr class="group-1"><td>patent 1 in group 1</td></tr>
     <tr class="group-1"><td>patent 2 in group 1</td></tr>
     <tr class="group-2"><td>patent 1 in group 2</td></tr>
     <tr class="group-2"><td>patent 2 in group 2</td></tr>
     <!-- etc -->
</table>
```

or multiple `TBODY` sections:

```
<table>
    <tbody class="group-1">
       <tr><td>patent 1 in group 1</td></tr>
       <tr><td>patent 2 in group 1</td></tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody class="group-2">
       <tr><td>patent 1 in group 2</td></tr>
       <tr><td>patent 2 in group 2</td></tr>
    </tbody>
    <!-- etc -->
</table>
```

Comment: I cannot use multiple tbody because the plugin limitation says u cannot drag and drop rows b/w mutiple tbodies

Comment: @ZohaAliKhan which plug-in are you using? are you using jquery?

Comment: @daviooh I am using TableDnD plugin for drag and drop http://www.isocra.com/2008/02/table-drag-and-drop-jquery-plugin/

Comment: @ZohaAliKhan so, i believe that the first solution i suggested you could work. one tbody section and css classes to group your rows.

Comment: The rows not static they comes dynamically from my database and I didn't get your different css classes solution